# ANTLR named function arguments / parameters in any order

Tags: antlr, named-parameters

I'm been looking for a way to have named function arguments / parameters appear in any order in ANTLR. Does anyone know if there is syntax to ignore order in an ANTLR parser expression?

Say there is a function `foo` in the language that can take two named parameters: `x` and `y`. Since they are named parameters, I'd like them to be able to be passed into the function in any order:

```
foo(x=1, y=2)
```

as well as

```
foo(y=2, x=1)
```

should both be legal.

I could just list all the parameter permutations in ANTLR, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution, especially since I have some functions that can take 5 parameters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I might be able to help, but the question is a little unclear to me. Can you give an example of what you're trying to parse?

Comment: Thanks Scott for your generous offer, and sorry for being unclear. An example is posted, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is nothing built in ANTLR to handle this. But you can simple sprinkle some regular programming logic in your grammar to reorganize the parameters.

Here's a little demo grammar:

```
grammar NF;

@parser::header {
    package antlrdemo;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Arrays;
}

@lexer::header {
    package antlrdemo;
}

parse   :   concat+
        ;

concat  :   'concat' '(' k1=Key '=' v1=Value ',' k2=Key '=' v2=Value ',' k3=Key '=' v3=Value ')' {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put($k1.text, $v1.text);
                params.put($k2.text, $v2.text);
                params.put($k3.text, $v3.text);
                HashSet<String> expected = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}));
                if(!params.keySet().equals(expected)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("No soup for you!");
                }
                System.out.println(params.get("a")+params.get("b")+ params.get("c"));
            }
        ;

Key     :   ('a'..'z')+
        ;

Value   :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')+
        ;

Space   :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n'){$channel = HIDDEN;}
        ;
```

And a little class to test it:

```
package antlrdemo;

import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class NFDemo {

    static void test(String source) throws RecognitionException {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(source);
        NFLexer lexer = new NFLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        NFParser parser = new NFParser(tokens);
        System.out.print(source+" -> ");
        parser.parse();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RecognitionException {
        test("concat(a=1, b=2, c=3)");
        test("concat(b=2, c=3, a=1)");
        test("concat(c=3, a=1, b=2)");
        test("concat(c=3, a=1, x=2)");
    }
}
```

which produces the output:

```
concat(a=1, b=2, c=3) -> 123
concat(b=2, c=3, a=1) -> 123
concat(c=3, a=1, b=2) -> 123
concat(c=3, a=1, x=2) -> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No soup for you!
    at antlrdemo.NFParser.concat(NFParser.java:137)
    at antlrdemo.NFParser.parse(NFParser.java:70)
    at antlrdemo.NFDemo.test(NFDemo.java:13)
    at antlrdemo.NFDemo.main(NFDemo.java:20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha...

If you want to hardwire "foo", "x" and "y" in your grammar, do the following (not compiled/tested, but should give the idea)

```
foo :
    { SomeType x=null, y=null; }
    'foo' '('
      (     'x' '=' {if (x != null) throw ...;} x=value
      |     'y' '=' {if (y != null) throw ...;} y=value
      )*
    ')'
    { if (x = null || y == null) throw ...; }
    ;
```

If you want more flexibility (to support other functions), do something like Bart's suggestion.